# Trouble rooting my Samsung Galaxy S Duos 2(gt-s7582)

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-duos-2

I have tried to root my device with odin 3.3 and everything went well. The software showed the result 'pass', but there is no `su` application. I have also installed ConnectBot and tried the command `su` but it hasn't worked. Please help me, I need to root the mobile because my device has got some problem, I lost my photos and to recover the images I have to root my mobile.

Comment: use vroot on pc. its very good application for root any android

Comment: Try using Kies2 or Kies3, it's good and will install samsung's firmware!

Answer (score 1):

What package were you using in Odin to flash your phone?  I don't think flashing a new OS in ODIN will help much with rooting.

Download towelroot on your phone, and root that way:  [Towelroot.com](http://towelroot.com)

Download and install the APK.  Click the lamda, and then install SuperSU from the Play Store.